# three.js cannot display the color of the objects in the b3dm file properly

Tags: angular, three.js, gltf

I'm currently trying to convert a `.b3dm` file to `.glft` and display it by loading it in [three.js](https://threejs.org/).

I mainly refer to this [article](https://medium.com/geekculture/3d-model-three-js-scene-in-angular-7bcbc0d00c31) for writing.
But there seems to be something wrong with reading, the object is only a single color.

I only changed the link to the image file, and the other codes have not been changed:

```
this.loaderGLTF.load('assets/test.gltf', (gltf: GLTF) => {
 ...
}
```

[image]

So I try to preview the archive with vscode [3rd party kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cesium.gltf-vscode).

1.I first convert the `.b3dm` format to `.glb` format through this [tool](https://github.com/CesiumGS/3d-tiles-validator/tree/main/tools).

```
node ./bin/3d-tiles-tools.js b3dmToGlb -i ./test.b3dm -f -o ./output/test.glb
```

2. Convert the `.glb` format to `.gltf` format through the vscode [3rd party kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cesium.gltf-vscode).

[image]

3. Preview 3D Model

[image]

I found that only `cesium` can display the color of objects properly：
[image]

`three.js` cannot render details and colors of objects：

[image]

I put three files in this place:
https://gitlab.com/po_developer/3d-test

Comment: You have to add the code to the question. This is not just a recommendation or "nice to have". Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I made a supplementary explanation, because I only changed the glft file link for the program of the reference example, so I will not repeat it. I checked my test file through the vscode third-party software, and three.js also failed to display properly, so I deduced that if the third-party software can view it normally, then my code should also work normally.

Answer (score 0):

This model's materials require the draft `KHR_techniques_webgl` extension to glTF — that extension was proposed some years ago, but ultimately the Khronos Group declined to approve it as an official extension (it can't work outside WebGL, for one thing). So three.js does not support this extension.

I haven't inspected the shader but this looks like a very simple material that could be better represented with the official PBR material standard in glTF.  If that's the case you can just replace the `materials` entry with this definition:

```json
{
      "alphaMode": "OPAQUE",
      "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
        "baseColorFactor": [1, 1, 1, 1],
        "baseColorTexture": { "index": 0 },
        "roughnessFactor": 1,
        "metallicFactor": 0
      }
}
```